# Вывести на html странице результат requests.get запроса на python

Tags: html, python, json, github, requests

Есть простейший скрипт на python

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/x/x.github.io")

repos = r.json()

print(repos['updated_at'])
```

Результат запроса дата обновления репозитория

Нужно вывести её на пустой html странице

Сама страница находится на github и доступна по адресу: https://x.github.io/test.html

Comment: `import json` не нужен. Вам нужно сделать запрос на `https://api.github.com/repos/x/x.github.io` и показывать результат его на своем сайте? А зачем редирект на другой домен?

Comment: Да, мне нужно вывести это на моем сайте x.github.io, сам запрос же я отправляю на api github

Comment: Показывать будете на github pages? Вам это надо https://github.com/gil9red/gil9red.github.io/blob/master/index.html ?

Comment: Да, github pages. Спасибо, это тоже можно использовать как вариант. Но хотелось бы все таки на python. Так как есть множество готовых python запросов к разным api, хотелось бы видеть результат их выполнения на github pages

Comment: github pages статичная страничка, к ней сервер не привязать, поэтому или делать на страничке запрос через js и выводить, либо свой сервер

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывести результат на пустой странице:

```
import logging

import requests
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    rs = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/x/x.github.io")
    repos = rs.json()
    return repos['updated_at']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```